# Pointing a stream object to another stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, io, stream

I have a file stream object in an external location and want to pass that stream as a file-like-object to pygresql. That works, however I want to make some changes to the stream with a replace.

```
import gzip
import pgdb

stream = gzip.open(external_location, 'r')
myConnection = pgdb.connect( host='x.x.x.X', user='test', password='test', database='test' )
cursor = myConnection.cursor()
cursor.copy_from(stream, 'test_table')
```

I don't want to save a temporary copy of the file locally. I want to point the stream directly to PostgreSQL, but make some changes for every iteration on the go.

```
stream = gzip.open(external_location, 'r')
manipulated_stream = (line.replace('a', 'b') for line in stream.readlines())
cursor.copy_from(manipulated_stream, 'test_table')
```

But then as a file-like object that I can pass to the copy_from command.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found [this](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#copy-data-from-a-string-iterator) solution, which basically creates a stringIOBase class from a generator expression.